# Stiffness ratio for purely imaginary eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation#Stiffness_ratio), the stiffness ratio of a system of ODEs is the ratio of the real part of the largest eigenvalue to the real part of the smallest eigenvalue (in modulus) of the Jacobian matrix. What if the system has purely imaginary eigenvalues say, $\pm i,\pm ai$, with $a>1$. What would be the stiffness ratio? $0/0$?

How to "measure" the stiffness of the following system of ODEs:

$$x' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -a^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiomatic definition of stiffness relies upon the real part of a complex number. Since it is pure imaginary numbers that have null real parts, it violates the axiomatic definition. Therefore undefined. $\square$

One must notice that the category "undefined" defines the categorization feasibility.

Addendum: The stiffness concept shows itself necessary for the stability analysis of numerical systems. (Refer to "Stability" section on article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Comment: Yeah I know but that's not really what I am asking. I clarified my question. Thanks,

Comment: The stiffness concept does not make sense (therefore "undefined") in aforementioned scenario since its bare (axiomatic) definition relies upon real part of imaginary complex numbers. I also clarify the answer.

Comment: So is it impossible to have a stiff system with oscillatory solution?

Comment: A pure oscillatory system does not have stiffness because this concept relates decay time constants.

Comment: A stiff dynamical system may have an oscillatory solution, but a pure oscilatory dynamical system cannot be stiff.

Comment: Aha that makes sense. Is there any classification for ODE systems whose eigenvalues are imaginary and they differ greatly in magnitude? Something may be along the line of dispersion or dissipation?

Comment: If it is not defined, it is defined-to-be. ;-)

Comment: Please, you must take a look at section "General theory" of following article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the clarification. It's weird. I am reading old literature where they talk about stiff oscillatory problems and I didn't understand how they measure stiffness.

Comment: The most simple physical example I know is an electro-mechanical actuated machine, a motor! Its electrical coils have very quick behavior respective to its mechanical part.